# How to access StateContext within an interceptor

Tags: spring-statemachine

I am trying to persist state machine when event is sent. To do so, I am using
the following code.

```
engine.getStateMachineAccessor()
                .doWithAllRegions(item -> {
                    item.addStateMachineInterceptor(new StateMachineInterceptorAdapter<String, String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void preStateChange(State state,
                                                   Message message,
                                                   Transition transition,
                                                   StateMachine stateMachine) 
                         {
                            _Logger.info("In the pre-state change stage"); 
                         }
```

From the documentation, StateContext is only available with preTransition and postTransition events, is there any way to obtain it with preStateChange event?

Comment: What's the issue of using preTransition ?

Comment: It has access to StateContext only, I need a method which has access to both StateContext as well as Messages. I am trying to send business data through the payload. But as it turned out, I can use either extended variables or chain postTransition (save stateContext to a variable) and postStateChange events.

Comment: Yes, if you want to pass in some business values inside the SM it's better to use the ExtendedContext.